# WCF service does not respond, how to debug?

Tags: wcf

consider a WCF service, which is heavily used and behaves normally. But then is stopps responding. In the sevice level message trace you can see the outgoing message on the client, but no incoming message on the server. On transport level theres a incoming message and then nothing. After 60 seconds the client throws a TimeoutException.

What can cause a behavior like this?

What would you do to debug this behavior?

Is it possible that this behavior is caused by too many concurrent connections/sessions?

EDIT:
Client and Server are on the same machine. Both are .NET apps. When the client is restarted the problem sometimes does not happen. Also the problem does only appear on a single machine. I was not able to reproduce the behavior on any other machine.

Regards

Michael

Answer (score 0):

I understand you have no problem on network level as you have mentioned that you can see incoming request on transport level. 
So the first thing to check does the service is up and does it works if the client is on the same machine.
Also you can analyze incoming messages may be the problem can be there.
Here [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/) will be your friend.

Also check can you view the wsdl from the client machine. By the way are your clients also .NET apps?

Comment: I clearified my question. The client is on the same machine and the same service method with the same client does sometimes work. So WSDL is ok.
I can see the incomming messages in the wcf message trace. Would WireShark provide additional information?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure tracing using the application’s configuration file—either Web.config for Web-hosted applications, or Appname.config for self-hosted applications by [Service Trace Viewer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx)

or use from debug tools such [Debug Diag](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/debugdiag/)