# WCF service not responding after some times

Tags: .net, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7.5

We have created a MVC application with WCF Service in .Net Framework 4.0. We have hosted both the application in Windows Server 2008 and IIS 7.0. My MVC Application sends requests to wcf service. Every 3 to 4 hours my application not responding. After restarting WCF in IIS it's working file.

I check the event log and found "A worker process with process id of  "xxxx" serving application pool "ASP.NET v4.0" has requested a recycle because the worker process reached its allowed processing time limit."

Can any one help me in identifying of the issue to solve it.

My application pool settings are shown below

[image]

Comment: please see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127449/wcf-service-does-not-respond-how-to-debug/43867060#43867060) Hopefully that will be useful

Answer (score 0):

Your AppPool must been recycled by IIS due to the default configuration. Select the AppPool and on "Actions" panel, click "Recycling.."

You can uncheck the "Regular time intervals" to avoid this. But the default value is 1740 minutes, what means 29 hours, check the value set to your AppPool, because this not match your 3 to 4 hours problem.

Anyway, a recycle does not put application unavailable, it starts again upon new requests.

If your AppPool is not starting some error can be happening, check the event log to find out any error during the restart of AppPool.

Comment: I have checked the event log but No any event log seen in event viewer. When i restart or recycle my application in IIS it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to upgrade to at least IIS 7.5, you could use IIS Application Initialisation. This will allow your application to recycle periodically, which is a Good Thing for its stability, without becoming periodically unavailable. That's because Application Initialisation overlaps IIS worker processes, starting up and initialising a new worker process before killing the old worker process. It magically deals with re-routing requests between the two worker processes.

Comment: Thanks PateAC,  I upgrade my IIS with 8.0 and i have check application Pool recycle. It is good feature. but my problem still not resolved.

Comment: To enable Application Initialisation, you also need to set PreloadEnabled=true on the application and StartMode=alwaysRunning on the application pool. Also note that Application Initialisation is an optional module in IIS 8 - you might find that you need to enable it in Windows Features. Here's a URL for one of many how-to articles that Googling would find: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2014/01/07/configure-the-iis-application-initialization-module/